# Were Sakura Haruno's parents ninjas?

Tags: naruto

Were Sakura's parents ninjas? I remember reading somewhere that they were, but she was said to have come from a civilian family?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, her parents are civilians.

In the movie: The road to Ninja, her parents were Ninjas (in the universe which Tobi made).

Comment: Actually sakura's father was a genin... It is mentioned in wikia http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kizashi_Haruno

Comment: But the Hokage, while introducing Kakashi to his team... he says that, "Sakura is from a civilian family".